# How can I apply the filter() function to select variable values?

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I'm looking for some guidance on applying the filter() function.

Below is an example of my data, I want to filter out investors with a 'treatment' year of 2006, 2007 and 2008.

An example of the data is below:

| investor | dealyear | dealcounts | treatment | other characteristics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 IM | 2003 | 5 | 2006 | various |
| 123 IM | 2004 | 5 | 2006 | various |
| 123 IM | 2005 | 5 | 2006 | various |
| 123 IM | 2006 | 5 | 2006 | various |
| 123 IM | 2007 | 5 | 2006 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2002 | 5 | 2008 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2003 | 5 | 2008 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2004 | 5 | 2008 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2005 | 5 | 2008 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2006 | 5 | 2008 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2007 | 5 | 2008 | various |
| 21 Invest | 2008 | 5 | 2008 | various |

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
result<- df %>% filter(!investor %in% unique(investor[treatment %in% 2006:2008]))
```

In base R -

```
result <- subset(df, !investor %in% unique(investor[treatment %in% 2006:2008]))
```